# blank page opening after uploading codeigniter code to server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have uploaded Codeigniter code to server but blank page is displayed when opening the URL

I am using codeingniter 2.1.3.

I used MY_Controller.php on application/core/ folder as per specification

I got error in error_log file of codeigniter

"PHP Fatal error:  Class 'My_Controller' not found in /home/nesterin/public_html/realstate/application/controllers/administrator/login.php on line 3"

can you tell what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with codeignighter. But I think if your class name is `My_Controller` and it's filename is `MY_Controller.php` autoloader probably won't find the file on a case sensitive file system.

Comment: Dear downvoter, why? I don't think case sensitivity is too bad of a guess. I don't use Codeigniter so I may have missed something but a downvote for what would normally be a mistake is a little harsh

Answer (score 0):

When you upload you need to check these steps:

1. Change Config file. New versions of CI you can let it blank. **CHECK base_url PLEASE!** Read [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html)
2. Change database.php and add new data for database. Read [Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html)

If you use the MY_Controller, than you need to check if you have the file in core folder and if you extend it correct in Controller too.

Hope that this answer will help you. If you face any problem, comment please!